# Drupal 7 + D3 - embed circle-pack visualization in a page

Tags: javascript, d3.js, drupal-7

I'm trying to embed a D3 circle-pack in a Drupal 7 basic, page but it's appearing in the wrong section of the page - below the footer. See here: http://www.thedata.co/circlepackzoom10. I've tried different themes but make no difference.

I'm using the php include method with the PHP filter: `<?php include './sites/thedata.co/files/html/circle_packZoom-10.html';` .

I'm able to embed a D3 chart in the node body so seems it can be done in some cases.

Using Chrome, JS console defines content area as: `<div class="field-item odd" property="content:encoded">`. Doesn't work with Firefox either.

Here's the complete code: http://jsfiddle.net/cajmcmahon/9a5xaovv/

```
var pack = d3.layout.pack()
    .size([r, r])
    .children(function(d) {
        return d.values; // accessor for children
    })
    .value(function(d) {
        return d.values; // accessor for values
    });

//Declare SVG attributes
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", w)
    .attr("height", w)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + (w - r) / 2 + "," + (w - r) / 2 + ")");
```

Anyone any idea how to place it within the main content area of the node? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Select the element where you want to put the chart instead of selecting "body" in d3.select("body").append("svg").

something like:

```
d3.select('#divID').append('svg') ... etc
```

As this method just appends it to the body element of the website.

Comment: Thanks! This got me headed in the right direction. Drupal theming is a bit tricky (lots of nesting). I tried 'div#main-content' and 'div#node-content' but didn't seem to work. I'm using 'var svg = d3.select('div#article-47').append("svg")' which get's it into the right position but means having to revise the code if I want to embed in another page. It's a Drupal challenge, I think. I'll post back if I get a system-wide solution, i.e. can be embedded in any page.

Comment: you may need to add a slight delay to the d3 code as drupal may take some time to plot the DOM.

Comment: Thanks. I haven't tried that before. I'll see if I can get it sorted.

Comment: I put the whole D3 script in 'window.onload = function() { console.log('Loaded..');   } just to ensure DOM is loading. It still seems 'div#article-47' is the best/only #divID to place it within so I'll leave it there for now. Thanks for you help!